SQL Query not working to get the monday from week number and year
I've been struggling to get the Monday from the week number and year number. Can anyone help? I would prefer that there is no reference made to 1900-01-01 because for 2022 the date that my query returns lands on a Saturday while the one for 2023 lands on a Sunday.
Here is the query I am using:
dateadd(week, weeknum - 1, dateadd(year, yearnum - 1900, '1900-01-01'))

To add more, the issue is that I don't want to refer to just -01-01 because for example if the data says week 50 2022, it returns to December 10, 2022 when it should return to December 12, 2022.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
Output for example for year 2022 and week 50 should be December 12 ,2022

Does this answer your question? How to convert number of week into date?

Hi @Harald, unfortunately it does not as my year and weeknum is dynamic

and I am using dbeaver

DBeaver is just an IDE, which can connect to a variety of different database types, each having very specific date functions. What is your DBMS? (ie, oracle, sql-server, postgres, etc).

I am using sql server @Isolated

my issue is that for example for week 50 2022, the date that the query returns is 2022-12-10 but it should be 2022-12-12

I don't understand the question nor the expected results. Adding 49 weeks to Saturday, January 1 2022 correctly returns Saturday, December 10 2022. Why do you think you should get December 12th? What are you trying to solution here?

December 12, 2022 is in w50 of 2022. December 10 is Week 49. I am trying to get the Monday for every week-year combination

i tried removing the - 1 (so as to not add just 49 weeks) from my query and it returns the Saturday of Week 50 (more correct). But what I would like to find is the monday date of each week - year combination

Realistically, what is your date range? Do you need to find the 32nd Monday of 1949? Or are you dealing with just 21st century dates? And do you care only about Mondays?

just 21st century dates specifically 2022 onward

I would consider making a calendar table and then inputting your YEAR, DOW and WEEK criteria into the where clause of a query. The recursive CTE below is one useful way to create a calendar table.
The RANK() windows function, as written below, counts how many times that day-of-week has been each year and ranks them. Don't confuse this with datepart(week) as it's different.
For example, December 12, 2022 is the 50th Monday of 2022. I assume you are looking for the Nth dow by year, which is why it's written as below.
create table calendar(
  cal_dt DATE, 
  year int, 
  dow int, 
  dow_ytd int
  );

--populate calendar table
with cte as (
  select convert(date, '2022-01-01') as cal_dt --start date
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, cal_dt)
  from cte
  where cal_dt <= '2049-12-31' --end date
  )
insert into calendar
select 
  cal_dt, 
  datepart(year, cal_dt) as year, 
  datepart(weekday, cal_dt) as dow, 
  rank() over (partition by datepart(year, cal_dt), datepart(weekday, cal_dt) order by cal_dt) as dow_ytd 
from cte
option (maxrecursion 32767);

select 
  cal_dt
from 
  calendar
where 
  year = 2022
  and dow_ytd = 50 --the Nth occurance of your targeted dow
  and dow = 2 --Monday





cal_dt




2022-12-12



fiddle
